# How to get my ggvis chart to update in R shiny app the same way as ggplot chart will?

Tags: r, ggplot2, charts, shiny, ggvis

I am very new to Shiny and ggvis both, I usually use ggplot for all my plotting needs.

To be brief, I have this dashboard set up for an interactive presentation (minimal example provided) and my ggplot bar chart will update just fine when I refresh the dataframe on the first page (connected to a survey which pushes to google sheets).

For various reasons I'd like to use a ggvis bar chart instead, but I can't figure out how to get it to update in the same way?

Here are the libraries I'm using (for the whole dashboard):

```
library(shiny)
library(googlesheets)
library(DT)
library(googleVis)
library(tidyr)
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(ggvis)
```

UI:

```
ui <- navbarPage("Find The Fuel",

             tabPanel("Data",
                      DT::dataTableOutput("SheetRound1"),
                      actionButton("refresh", "Refresh Sheet")),
             tabPanel("Chart",
                      plotOutput("ChartRound1", width = 800, height = 300)),
             tabPanel("Chart2",
                      ggvisOutput("p"),
                      uiOutput("p_ui"))
                 )
```

Server:

```
GoogleSheetRound1 <- "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xC9qL6cOTlxyJg47BR2-YYJ-ED558Y-oG812Qeff8hM/pubhtml"

server <- function(input, output, session) {

sheet1 <- gs_url(GoogleSheetRound1, lookup = FALSE, visibility = "public")

output$SheetRound1 <- renderDataTable({
input$refresh
sheet1_dat <- gs_read(sheet1) %>%
  select(Time, Name, Blue, Green, Orange, Purple, Red) %>%
  replace_na(replace = list(Blue = 0, Green = 0, Orange = 0, Purple = 0, Red = 0)) %>% 
  arrange(desc(Time))

DT::datatable(sheet1_dat, options = list(dom = "t", style = "font-family: 'Segoe UI'"), 
              class = "cell-border stripe",
              rownames = FALSE)
}) 

output$ChartRound1 <- renderPlot({
input$refresh
df1 <- gs_read(sheet1) %>% 
  replace_na(replace = list(Blue = 0, Green = 0, Orange = 0, Purple = 0, Red = 0)) %>% 
  select(-c(Time, Name)) %>%
  filter(Blue <= 1 & Green <= 1.75 & Orange <= 1.25 & Purple <= 1.5 & Red <= 2) %>% 
  summarise_each(funs(mean), Blue, Green, Orange, Purple, Red) %>% 
  melt
ggplot(df1, aes(variable, value, fill = variable))+
  geom_col()+
  theme_minimal()+ theme(legend.position = "none")+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#0084b8", "#4da84f", "#e66747", "#64346b", "#b83100"))+
  coord_flip(ylim = c(0,2))+
  geom_hline(yintercept = 1, color = "Gray", size = 3)
})

df1 <- gs_read(sheet1) %>% 
  replace_na(replace = list(Blue = 0, Green = 0, Orange = 0, Purple = 0, Red = 0)) %>% 
  select(-c(Time, Name)) %>%
  filter(Blue <= 1 & Green <= 1.75 & Orange <= 1.25 & Purple <= 1.5 & Red <= 2) %>% 
  summarise_each(funs(mean), Blue, Green, Orange, Purple, Red) %>% 
  melt %>%
  ggvis(x = ~value, y = ~variable, fill = ~variable) %>%
  scale_ordinal("fill", range = c("#0084b8", "#4da84f", "#e66747", "#64346b", "#b83100")) %>% 
  scale_numeric("x", domain = c(0, 2)) %>% 
  layer_rects(x2 = 0, height = band()) %>% 
  bind_shiny("p", "p_ui")


}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: It works as expected on my setup : win7, R_3.3.2, shiny_1.0.0, googlesheets_0.2.1, DT_0.2.10, googleVis_0.6.2, tidyr_0.6.1, reshape2_1.4.2, ggplot2_2.2.1, dplyr_0.5.0, ggvis_0.4.3

Comment: I probably was not specific enough but the issue was that when participants are filling out the survey and I refresh the datatable, the bar chart was not updating. I did figure out how it works though, I put the chart code inside a reactive ({    }) with the input$refresh and bind_shiny right after the reactive  and it works perfectly! I guess I just wasn't understanding the difference between the ggvis reactivity and the render type.